# Showing popUp after clicking on listView item

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I have created a list, which when a item is clicked, a popup is shown.

The problem starts when using the code on a mobile device (where the screen is relatively small). When a list item is hit, very often, also a button in the popop is hit.

What is the best way to deactivate the buttons until the user realizes the popup even did show?

Try the [code here](http://jsfiddle.net/6p4Fq/1/).

The HTML code:

```
<div data-role="page" id="kon">
    <div data-role="content">
        <ul data-role="listview" id="kon_list" data-icon="false">           
        </ul>   

        <div data-role="popup" id="contactMsgBox" data-transition="pop">
                <div data-role="content" data-theme="d" class="ui-corner-bottom ui-content">
                    <h3 class="ui-title">Ansprechpartner kontaktieren</h3>
                    <a href="#" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-rel="back" data-theme="c" style="width:95%">Anrufen</a> <br />
                    <a href="#" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-rel="back" data-theme="c" style="width:95%">E-Mail senden</a> <br />    
                    <a href="#" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-rel="back" data-transition="flow" data-theme="b" style="width:95%">Abbrechen</a>  
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>      
</div>
```

The JS code:

```
kontakts = JSON.parse('[{"mail":"test@test.de",'+
                    '"name":"test test","ort":"Stuttgart","tel":"0123 1234-123"},{"mail":"test2@test.de",'+
                    '"name":"test2 test2","ort":"Lauf","tel":"0123 1234-123"}]');

var listHTML = "";
for(var i=0; i<kontakts.length; i++) 
{
    //set the menu item
    listHTML = listHTML + "<li tel='"+kontakts[i].tel+
        "' mail='"+kontakts[i].mail.toLowerCase()+"'><h3>" + kontakts[i].ort + 
        "</h3><p>" + kontakts[i].name + "<br />Telefon\t" + kontakts[i].tel + 
        "<br />E-Mail\t" + kontakts[i].mail.toLowerCase() + "</p></li>";        
}

//set items and reload
$('#kon_list').html(listHTML);
$('#kon_list').listview('refresh');

//bind list items
$('#kon_list').children('li').bind('touchstart mousedown', function(e) {
    //alert('Selected Tel=' + $(this).attr('tel') + 'Mail=' + $(this).attr('mail'));
    $("#contactMsgBox").popup("open");
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is happening because mobile browsers wait approximately 300ms (apparently 500ms on samsung galaxy s2) from the time that you tap the button to fire the click event. This wait was causing both to be tapped, the item, and the popup button.

The solution is to stop the browser from waiting. This can be accomplished with the [fastclick library](https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick)

Answer (score 1):

You could change

```
$('#kon_list').children('li').bind('touchstart mousedown', function(e) {
```

to

```
$('#kon_list').children('li').bind('vclick', function(e) {
```

That way the popup won't show until the user lifts his finger or releases the mouse button.

Comment: I get the same behavior with vclick

Comment: I haven't tested on any mobile device but it works as expected when running your jfiddle on my desktop. Maybe you could try clearing your browser cache? Or did you maybe miss to remove mousedown?

Comment: My code also works on desktop. I did replace 'touchstart mousedown' with 'vclick', I also tried 'touchend mouseup'

Comment: Btw. I most definitely have lifted my finger when the popup shows with 'vclick', but it seems to remember where i clicked last

Comment: if a set a short timeout like 300ms `setTimeout(function() { $("#contactMsgBox").popup("open"); }, 300);` I don't get any clicks on the popup anymore, but..its kinda ugly

Comment: and it depends on the device, on Samsung Galaxy 2 I need 500ms